After building ReactTS app some "display: flex" disappears
in my ReactTS app I got some places where my css gets changed after running the command:
npm run build

I build the app and then deployed it using surge and I notice that in some places it's just gone...
Btw after adding it back using the dev tools (F12) it goes back to the way I did it.
Any one knows why it happens? tried searching for a solution with no luck.
Also I've noticed that in the build files the file is actually changed and the display: flex; is deleted.
Edit: Btw, when using display: grid; it doesn't do it.

Example for it:



look after if there, any css file over-riding this code css classes..

There is no other place that uses this class nor this CSS file.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
